# turn serialized form into invisible form and submit

Tags: jquery

How can I take a serialized form array and create an invisible form and then submit it using jQuery?

Comment: What's a "serialized form array"? Do you mean it's a JS object with properties?

Answer (score 2):

Do you still have "file" inputs?  If so, this won't work. Go look at the answer I posted in your "multiple form submit" question.  You're going to have to pile all the non-file inputs into the form that's got the completed file inputs in it, and then submit that one.  You can't dynamically create file inputs with values; the browser won't let you (security).

The other question is here: [submit multiple forms to same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368593/submit-multiple-forms-to-same-page)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, whoever you are!  After all, I had the gall to provide an answer to the question Brian's asked like six different times tonight, and to try and explain over and over again why the approaches he so weirdly desires to pursue won't work.

Comment: @David ha ha, thanks, I guess.  It wasn't so much a religious statement as a substitute for something I **really** wanted to type :-)