# Submit forms, one after another with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How can I set up an automated queue system to run multiple submits, one after another? I don't want them to submit at once, or it may break my backend PHP script.

Here's a simple example, assuming each form can submit independently, and a master submit will run all the forms in series.

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_all" value="Submit All" />

<form id="form-1" method="post" action="function.php">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form-2" method="post" action="function.php">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form-3" method="post" action="function.php">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

UPDATE:

The script I'm working on is tool to backup the FTP files and MySQL dump of multiple websites - essentially an automated backup tool for web administrators.

Each form contains the values to connect to the FTP and MySQL of each site, and the PHP function copies and stores the files locally and creates a MySQL dump.

Copying the files can take 20+ minutes per site, so the idea is to create a 'master button' to automate each backup, one after the other.

Comment: Do you want to submit all the forms individually *at the same time*, or each form after the previous is done?

Comment: I'd prefer each form after the previous is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this jQuery example. I coded it on the fly, so it's not tested - but you get what I'm trying to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var state = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit_all').click(function() {
        go();

        // get all forms on the page
        $forms = $('form');
        sent = 0;

        // post the form (non-async)
        $forms.each(function() {
            if(state) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                url: $(this).attr("action"), 
                data: $(this).serialize(), 
                success: function(data) { 
                    if(++sent == $forms.length) {
                        alert("All forms submitted!");
                    }
                }
            });
            } else { return false; }
        });
        stop();
    });

    $('#cancel').hide().click(stop);

    function go() {
        if(!state) {
            state = true;
            $('#submit_all').hide();
            $('#cancel').show();
            $('input[type=button], input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }}

    function stop() {
        if(state) {
            state = false;
            $('#submit_all').show();
            $('#cancel').hide();
            $('input[type=button], input[type=submit]').removeAttr("disabled");
    }}
});
</script>

<input type="button" id="submit_all" value="Submit All" />
<input type="button" id="cancel" value="Cancel" />

<form id="form-1" method="post" action="function.php">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form-2" method="post" action="function.php">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form id="form-3" method="post" action="function.php">
<input type="text" name="foo" value="Foo" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot in the morning!

Comment: The script works perfectly! One more thing... How would I assign a button to cancel the process mid way?

Comment: Two issues... Console is showing an error "Illegal break statement", and second, should the click event on #cancel be stop() instead of stop?

Comment: Also learned that my PHP scripts needed the async: to be set to true, else they timed out too early. Thanks again - the script was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would set up some simple javascript which would simply be a series of submits.  It would be something like:

```
function submitAll() {
   document.forms["form-1"].submit();
   document.forms["form-2"].submit();
   document.forms["form-3"].submit();
}
```

Obviously you may need to ajaxify the process as submitting a form will halt javascript execution.

I agree with other answers that this appears to be a logic error on your behalf and you should look at integrating the forms instead of plastering over the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If one form relies on two other forms, it sounds like they're really part of the same form, and the backend should just figure out which parts of that one mega-form (with different sets of data, but for one form) that are needed. On a similar note, it's best not to rely on javascript alone anyway, so doing it this way provides you with an automatically more robust solution.

Update If you have multiple forms that are just sharing data (like they can change data on form1 and form2 that form3 needs), it would be more stable, especially in light of validation, to put those shared things in hidden elements and leave the forms separate. Having users enter data that will be submitted and used and then hiding it from view isn't optimal, since they can more easily make entry mistakes (they can't review as easily and they may not understand it will all be submitted). Using < input type="hidden" />s for shared info alleviates this because they won't be able to accidentally change it. (Or store it in the session or whatever you'd like. Point is, prevent them from changing info that you're going to rely upon and they can't easily spot mistakes in.)

Form element returns a value (true/false) when you submit it.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362251/jquery-submit-multiple-forms)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#submit_all").click(function(){
    $("#form-1").submit();
    $("#form-2").submit();
    $("#form-3").submit();
})
```

Maybe better for you to redesign your application (front/back)?

```
<form method="post" action="./function.php">
    <input type="text" name="foo[]" value="Foo" />
    <input type="text" name="foo[]" value="Foo" />
    <input type="text" name="foo[]" value="Foo" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit_all" value="Submit All" />
</form>
```