# Submitting 2 forms on one click - one form relies on results from the other one

Tags: php, jquery, forms, form-submit

Here is the situation - On my Order page I have 2 forms: "Order Submit" and "Pay Paypal button" for total. Clients have to submit 2 forms (one after another) - I want to bring it back to one Submit.

Setup:

Form 1: Calls a submit.php script (calculations + order array) that is sent to Commerce on submit.

Form 2: Calls Paypal script for payment of total.

The way it works now: clients Submit Form 2 (Paypal), Ipn.php gets the "Completed" notice when payment is accepted and updates DBase with payment info.
Then Clients have to submit Form 1 that updates payment information from Dbase (Amount to pay = 0). Commerce gets order with updated payment info.

I want Clients to Submit only Form 2 (Paypal), and the rest to be done automatically.

A) Form 1 updates from Dbse

B) Form 1 submits itself automaticaly after update.

My php files.

1) submit.php (I have control over it)

2) Paypal (I have no control over it)

3) Ipn.php (I have control over it)

Form 1:

```
  <form action="../../order/submit.php" id="Formulaire" method="post" name="Formulaire" target="preview">

  <button id="submit" class="buttonsubmit" name="_Commande" onclick="return checkform();" type="submit">
         Order / Commandez </button>
```

Form 2:

```
 <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" name="Paypal" target="_blank" id="Paypal">

 <button class="buttonsubmitpaypal" id="buttonpaypal" name="_Paypal" onclick="alert('IMPORTANT: you MUST come back WITHOUT refreshing browser, click PREVIEW to reflect payment then SUBMIT your order.');PayPalSubMitFinal();" />
```

I saw an article with maybe the solution for me, although (since I am not a programmer - but I can adapt), I am not sure it is the right solution for me, and I do not really understand how to implement:

[Submit forms, one after another with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7737286/submit-forms-one-after-another-with-jquery)

The solution I am thinking of, not sure it is realistic:

Integrate Ipn.php to my Submit.php script and when Paypal sent the "Completed" notice, it triggers the submit mechanism. Do not know how to implement the "listen part of if". But then, the script would not have get the info from order form 1... so...

Thanks for your hints.

Updated - Testing solution suggested below:

I integrated ipn.php in my submit.php form, and on "Completed" notice received, I added :

```
  $emailto = 'me@me.ca';      // this is to ckeck if it works - I receive it.
  $subject = $_POST['payment_status'];
  $text ="success submit IPN". $_POST['custom'];
  $headers = 'From: "" <"' . $_POST['payment_status']. '">'. "\r\n".
  "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
  mail($emailto, $subject, $text, $headers);
```

// Then I trigger the script provided (I tested it somewhere else, it works)

```
  $click = '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.parent.parent.submitsubmit();</script>';
  echo $click;
```

Script itself:

```
 function submitsubmit() {
 $("#submit").click();
 }
```

Result: submit button is not triggerred. I cannot see what is wrong.

I simplified my issue in a new question here :

[Can we trigger a script on original window even if script runs in _blank window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573336/can-we-trigger-a-script-on-orinal-window-even-if-script-runs-in-blank-window)

Comment: Why not just run the whole process when the user submits the second form?

Answer (score 0):

Once Paypal sends the Completed notice, you can use jQuery to detect this and submit the second form. You will need to include jQuery.
The jQuery include (HTML/PHP):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The check-and-submit code:

```
if(completed) {        // Assuming completed is a variable representing the
// state of the completed notice
    $("#submit").click();
    // "submit" is the ID of the second form's submit button.
    // This statement selects this button and clicks it, which fires the
    // form's action attribute as it would if the user clicked Submit.
}
else {
    throw new Error("Paypal form not submitted");
    location.href = "paypalform.html";
}
```

Hope this goes some way to helping.
-CE

Comment: We are on the way! "Completed" is data saved in my Dbase when Ipn.php received confirmation from Paypal. So, with your input, how could I (in my submit.php script) write something like: Whenever db field in question returns "Completed" { $("#submit").click(); }

Comment: Ok, I think I know how to try that, I will report!

Comment: I tested (see original posting - update at the end). No success so far.

Comment: @user3371049: I'm writing in Javascript there. To check DB fields you need PHP. One possible way of doing this is to check your DB with a PHP script and `echo` the results into a CSS-hidden `<div>`. Then you can get the content with jQuery: `$("#hidden-div").text();` and if it is a certain value submit the form as above.

Comment: Alternatively having just looked again at the question, instead of echoing the result, test it within PHP and echo the `<script>` with the submit code.