# Can we trigger a script on original window even if script runs in _blank window

Tags: javascript, jquery, target

Here is the setup:

On Paypal click button (openned in _blank) My focus window becomes Paypal, is it possible to run a script in original window.

Right now my script is (and it works well if target is within iframe of original page - but Paypal does do not allow it, that's why I have the issue):

```
  $click = '<script type="text/javascript">window.top.parent.parent.submitsubmit();</script>';
  echo $click;
```

Just wondering if what I want to do is realistic,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please read [Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). For security reasons, it is not possible to execute JavaScript that can read or modify a page without proper headers, namely, [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: Thanks, I will spend the week-end (and more) to understand it! :)

Comment: See [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) for cross domain, cross window/frame communication.  It works well, but requires two cooperating windows/frames which is why it's safe.

Comment: Thanks, I am on the way...

Comment: Here id where I am now, I posted a new question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23636016/window-postmessage-difficulties-to-make-it-work

Answer (score 0):

Scripting towards a window that has been opened in a _blank is possible. However accessing the contents is not possible when the opened url is of a different (sub)domain.

Comment: I think you helped me before! What I want to do is simulate click on original page when Paypal Ipn.php receives notice that transaction is complete. Everything is setup, although the function is not triggered. (all is on same domain).